# Android: AdapterContextInfo

Tags: android

I've already set up the contextmenu code on my ListView, and also i have already done the adaptercontextinfo to get the position from where i longpressed the item from listview, so my problem is how to access the members or views in that item using the adaptercontextinfo

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
    ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
MenuItem edit = menu.add("Edit");
MenuItem delete = menu.add("Delete");

edit.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(PatientActivity.this, Long.toString(info.id), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

so my question is how do i access the views in that item that i long clicked..

[image]

I wanted to access that small numbers above the name on that picture.. i have already determined the position from where i long clicked it.. but i don't know how to access what i clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the row's layout from an AdapterContextMenuInfo use: `info.targetView`. You can use this and findViewById() to fetch the number in the upper-left of your layout.

I don't know what you mean by members in your question, but if the number you want is an id like a primary key in a SQLiteDatabase you can simply use: `info.id`.

Also consider using the [onContextItemSelected()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onContextItemSelected%28android.view.MenuItem%29) method with is available in Activities and Fragments, instead of writing individual onMenuItemClickListeners. (It's less work than creating listener after listener.)

Comment: u mean onContextItemSlected()? yep, tried using that but it has some problem cuz the ListView i am using isn't a normal ListView, its on a Dialog Box.. but anyways, it works fine, the targetView.. thank you very much!

Comment: Whoops, good catch! I updated my answer and added a suggestion if the number you want is a unique key.